# Alamofire reponse invaid json in swift 5

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire, swift5

I am using Swift 5 and Alamofire 5 but the response is invalid JSON. I have called Postman where the response JSON is:

```
[ {
    "location_name": "Hamdard(waqf) Limited, Pantha Path, ধানমন্ডি আ/এ, লালমাটিয়া, ঢাকা, ঢাকা বিভাগ, বাংলাদেশ",
    "description": "D M-Th 16-0299",
    "engine": 1
{
  "location_name": "602/Chha, Red Crescent Shorak, Mogbazar, ঢাকা, ঢাকা বিভাগ, বাংলাদেশ",
    "description": "D M-Th 16-1953",
    "engine": 1   
}   ]
```

I have called Alamofire like this:

```
 let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "YumaSession": "my session_id"
        ]

    AF.request(url,method:.get,encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON  { response in

            switch response.result {
            case .success(let response):                 

                print("response--",response)

            case .failure(let error):

                print("error--->",error)
            }
```

But Alamofire returns a JSON response with Unicode like this:

```
 ({
    description = "D M-Th 16-0299";    
    "location_name" = "357 Modubag,Mogbazar, \U09a2\U09be\U0995\U09be, \U09a2\U09be\U0995\U09be \U09ac\U09bf\U09ad\U09be\U0997, \U09ac\U09be\U0982\U09b2\U09be\U09a6\U09c7\U09b6";
    lon = "90.41140444444444";
    online = 1;

},
    {
    description = "D M-Th 16-1953";       
    "location_name" = "53, Gulshan, \U0997\U09c1\U09b2\U09b6\U09be\U09a8 \U09e7, \U09a2\U09be\U0995\U09be, \U09a2\U09be\U0995\U09be \U09ac\U09bf\U09ad\U09be\U0997, 1212, \U09ac\U09be\U0982\U09b2\U09be\U09a6\U09c7\U09b6";
    lon = "90.40848888888888";
    online = 1;

}  )
```

Please help me to get the correct JSON response.

Comment: try to use swiftyJSON if you have already use alamofire. then you can directly get json response. no need for jsonencoder . after that use just let jsonData = json(response.result)

Comment: That's not the JSON response, that's the printed description of decoded JSON from `responseJSON`. The unicode is just an artifact of how it's being printed. If you want to see the raw body string, use `debugPrint(response)`.

Comment: You have to update about your question. If you found workable solution then please accept answer. Press the up vote and tick symbol

Answer (score 0):

By the way It's very simple. You have to follow `Codable`approach. 
Here is my answer. Hopefully it will help you. I created local json file you can pass url accordingly.

Your JSON: You missing one curly brackets and comma.

```
[ {
    "location_name": "Hamdard(waqf) Limited, Pantha Path, ধানমন্ডি আ/এ, লালমাটিয়া, ঢাকা, ঢাকা বিভাগ, বাংলাদেশ",
    "description": "D M-Th 16-0299",
    "engine": 1

},
{
  "location_name": "602/Chha, Red Crescent Shorak, Mogbazar, ঢাকা, ঢাকা বিভাগ, বাংলাদেশ",
    "description": "D M-Th 16-1953",
    "engine": 1
}   ]
```

Model:

```
struct DataClass : Codable {

        let descriptionField : String?
        let engine : Int?
        let locationName : String?

        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
                case descriptionField = "description"
                case engine = "engine"
                case locationName = "location_name"
        }

        init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
                let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
                descriptionField = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .descriptionField)
                engine = try values.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .engine)
                locationName = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .locationName)
        }

}
```

Code:

```
var AppData = [DataClass]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "file", withExtension: "json") {
            do {

                let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
                 let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let jsonData = try decoder.decode(Array<DataClass>.self, from: data)
                self.AppData = jsonData
                print (jsonData.first?.locationName ?? "")

            } catch {
                print("error:\(error)")
            }
        }
    }
```

Prints:

```
Hamdard(waqf) Limited, Pantha Path, ধানমন্ডি আ/এ, লালমাটিয়া, ঢাকা, ঢাকা বিভাগ, বাংলাদেশ
```

Answer (score 0):

Include the library **SwiftyJSON** , the use this simple approach below:

```
 AF.request(url,method:.get,encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON  { response in

            let value = response.result.value
            let json = JSON(value)
            print("response**:\(json)")
    }
```

Comment: Since Swift 4 SwiftyJSON has become obsolete in favor of `Codable`

Comment: Yes of course, first let him learn this, eventually he will learn others I hope